# ¿Como puedo crear columnas desorganizadas en bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quisiera crear algo como esto: https://www.apptrendit.com/

Pero quisiera crearlo mediante a `bootstrap` para hacerlo responsive, el problema es que las columnas tienen distintos tamaños y no van lineales como cuando uno trabaja las columnas en `bootstrap`, ¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Mi Intento: https://jsfiddle.net/370z66u2/

Comment: debes usar el sistema de rejillas aqui esta la documentacion: http://mialtoweb.es/sistema-de-rejillas-en-bootstrap-4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hasta donde yo se, en `boostrap` no es posible con css puro. En algún punto de la [documentación](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails) dice algo así:

> Si tu estas buscando presentar miñaturas al estilo Pinterest, donde estas
>   son de distintas alturas y / o anchuras, tendrás que utilizar un
>   *plugin* de terceros, tales como: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) o [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/).

Ya que tienes distintas dimensiones en las imágenes te dejos un ejemplo utilizando [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), es una librería para hacer grillas que se auto organizan. [Aquí](http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html) tienes un ejemplo hecho con esta librería.

Para utilizar Masonry en tu `fiddle` debes:

Incluir JQuery y Masonry:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.0.0/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Inicializar la grilla:

```
<script>
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
</script>
```

Aquí he modificado tu fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91ydtqy1/

Comment: esto es justo lo que buscaba! gracias!

Comment: lo intento utilizar pero de todas maneras me quedan espacios entre cada una y queda todo desordenado, mira como aquí puedes ver 
https://jsfiddle.net/370z66u2/

Comment: @DavidBazzingaJuggling acabo de editar la respuesta .... he dejado un fiddle.

Comment: o sea editaste el mismo fiddle o es otro?

Comment: ya lo vi!, increible! cual era el problema?

Comment: faltaba agregar el codigo para invocar a masonry :)

Comment: ya veo, te pasaste!

Comment: @DavidBazzingaJuggling la proxima vez que hagas una pregunta, si tenes un fiddle, ponelo en pregunta, eso hará mas fácil responder.

Comment: es que alguien coloco un display box para chrome en el codigo..
luego de formular la pregunta lo encontre

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer algo parecido a lo que buscas con CSS puro usando [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/column-count). Con `column-count` especificas en cuántas columnas quieres que se muestre el contenido de un elemento. Así, si les pones un ancho de 100% a los elementos, van a ocupar el 100% del ancho de la columna en lugar del 100% del ancho del contenedor.

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo simple funcionando:

```css
div {
  column-count: 3;  
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/ccc/666/?text=1" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x200/ccc/666/?text=2" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x200/ccc/666/?text=3" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc/666/?text=4" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100/ccc/666/?text=5" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x200/ccc/666/?text=6" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x250/ccc/666/?text=8" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x500/ccc/666/?text=9" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x200/ccc/666/?text=10" alt="" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200/ccc/666/?text=11" alt="" />
</div>
```

Dos inconvenientes de este método:

1. No va a funcionar en versiones antiguas de IE (requiere IE10 o superior) y puede que necesites el prefijo de navegador para versiones antiguas de Chrome/Firefox.
2. Los elementos se ordenan verticalmente (lo puedes ver en el ejemplo de arriba), si quieres que se ordenen de forma horizontal vas a tener que hacerlo antes de mostrarlos porque de momento no existe esa opción en CSS puro.